# Update multiple rows in php and mysql by checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

On my GUI in html y have this code for show de table

```
                <table  class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id="dynamic-table"  >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>CURRENT USER</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>ID FACTORY</th>
                            <th>CATEGORY</th>
                            <th>MODEL</th>
                             <th>DB</th>
                            <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                            <th>STATUS</th>                     
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                     <!--PHP module-->
                    <?php require '../../modules/associativedevicesbackend.php';?>
                     <!--PHP module-->

             </table>

           </form>

         </div>
```

and in the back I fill the table with this :

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($searchnodes))

 {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" value=\"\" id=\"checkbox\"></td>";
  echo"<td> $row[USER_NAME] </td>";
  echo"<td align='right'> $row[DEVICE_ID] </td>";
  echo "<td> $row[DEVICE_FACTORY_ID] </td>";
  echo "<td> $row[CATEGORY_NAME] </td>";
   echo "<td> $row[DEVICE_MODEL] </td>";
 echo "<td> $row[DEVICE_BELONGING] </td>";
 echo "<td> $row[DEVICE_DESCRIPTION] </td>";
  echo"<td> $row[DEVICE_STATUS] </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }    cxz
```

how can i send the data of the textbox to another fill to process to the UPDATE

Comment: wheres your SQL query for UPDATE? what you can do is make a FORM with a "update" button. When it gets clicked it will run the UPDATE query. Thats how I would do it

Comment: By the way, ID's have to be unique so you have to change the ID's or use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to distinguish what checkboxes were marked when you send in the form, you have 2 options:

1. Give every checkbox a unique name so that you know which one was checked:
   `... name=\"checkbox[{$row[DEVICE_ID]}]\" ...`
2. Give every checkbox a unique value (for the same reason...):
   `.. value=\"{$row[DEVICE_ID]}\" ...`

Assuming that `{$row[DEVICE_ID]}` uniquely identifies your row of course.

Now you can loop over your checkboxes array in php and based on the key or the value you will know exactly which one was checked.

Note that only checked checkboxes get sent to the server when you send in your form.